# How to prove parents without a birth certificate

Tags: united-states

I have to prove to a government office that my parents are in fact my parents. A birth certificate would work, but that is not an option as of now.

Are there any other ways for me to affirm who my parents are without using a birth certificate?

Comment: Court order would be one method--but probably only to be used to get a new birth certificate.

Comment: Can you say what government office, and why? That might affect the answer.

Comment: Birth certificates can be obtained from the state of birth. If you don't have one, you can get one with the proper information (which you should have from memeory if it's your certificate).

Comment: @Patrick87, the DMV for a permit

Comment: @Scott, I have one, just not with me (it's in a different state)

Comment: Depends upon the DMV's regulations. Often an affirmation from a parent that you are their child would suffice, but Real ID laws are tightening up requirements. You can order a duplicate birth certificate from the vital statistics department of the state although it could take time and there would be a fee.